# Fetching Django API with pagination in react

Tags: python, reactjs, django, endpoint

I have this code in my react:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
import { Bar } from 'react-chartjs-2';
import moment from 'moment';
import 'chartjs-adapter-moment';
import { MultiSelect } from "react-multi-select-component";

const AllFilters = () => {
  const [startDate, setStartDate] = useState(null);
  const [endDate, setEndDate] = useState(null);
  const [operatorId, setOperatorId] = useState(null);
  // const [statuses, setStatuses] = useState([]);
  const [operatorsList, setOperatorsList] = useState([]);
  const [orderStatuses, setOrderStatuses] = useState([]);
  const [orders, setOrders] = useState([]);
  const [selectedStatuses, setSelectedStatuses] = useState([]);
  const [viewBy, setViewBy] = useState('month');

  const filterOrdersByDay = (day) => {
    const formattedDay = moment(day).format('YYYY-MM-DD');
    const filteredOrders = orders.filter(order => moment(order.created_at).isSame(formattedDay, 'day', 'minute'));
    console.log(`Filtered orders for day ${formattedDay}:`, filteredOrders);
    return filteredOrders;
  };

  const getStatusCountByDay = (status, day) => {
    const formattedDay = moment(day).format('YYYY-MM-DD');
    return filterOrdersByDay(formattedDay).filter(order => order.status === status).length;
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
      try {
        const loginToken = localStorage.getItem('loginToken');
        const operatorsListResponse = await axios.get('http://localhost:8000/accounts/profile/operators/', {
          headers: {
            Authorization: `Token ${loginToken}`,
          },
        });
        const orderStatusesResponse = await axios.get('http://localhost:8000/dashboard/OrderStatus/', {
          headers: {
            Authorization: `Token ${loginToken}`,
          },
        });

        setOperatorsList(operatorsListResponse.data);
        setOrderStatuses(orderStatusesResponse.data);
        
        let pageOrders = [];

        const response = await axios.get('http://localhost:8000/dashboard/AllFilters/', {
          headers: {
            Authorization: `Token ${loginToken}`,
          },
          params: {
            start_date: startDate ? moment(startDate).format('YYYY-MM-DD') : null,
            end_date: endDate ? moment(endDate).format('YYYY-MM-DD') : null,
            pk: operatorId ? operatorId : null,
            status: selectedStatuses.map((status) => status.value).join(','),
          },
        });
        
        while (response.data.next) {
          let myUrl = response.data.next;
          const PageResponse = await axios.get(myUrl, {
            headers: {
              Authorization: `Token ${loginToken}`,
            },
            params: {
              start_date: startDate ? moment(startDate).format('YYYY-MM-DD') : null,
              end_date: endDate ? moment(endDate).format('YYYY-MM-DD') : null,
              pk: operatorId ? operatorId : null,
              status: selectedStatuses.map((status) => status.value).join(','),
            },
          });
          
          pageOrders = [...pageOrders, ...PageResponse.data.results];
        
          // If there is another page, update the response variable for the next iteration
          // if (PageResponse.data.next) {
          //   response = PageResponse;
          // } else {
          //   break;
          // }
        }
        
        // Concatenate the results from the first page with the accumulated orders
        // setOrders([...response.data.results, ...pageOrders]);
        pageOrders(response.data.results);


  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Failed to fetch data:', error);
  }
};

fetchData();
  }, [startDate, endDate, operatorId, selectedStatuses]);

  const generateDateRange = () => {
    const dateRange = [];
    let currentDate = moment(startDate);
    while (currentDate.isSameOrBefore(endDate, 'day')) {
      dateRange.push(currentDate.format('YYYY-MM-DD'));
      currentDate.add(1, 'day');
    }
    return dateRange;
  };

  const filterOrdersByMonth = (month, year) => {
    return orders.filter(
      order =>
        moment(order.created_at).month() === month - 1 && moment(order.created_at).year() === year
    );
  };

  const getStatusCount = (status, date) => {
    const formattedDate = moment(date).format('YYYY-MM-DD');
    const filteredOrders = viewBy === 'month'
      ? filterOrdersByMonth(moment(date).month() + 1, moment(date).year())
      : filterOrdersByDay(date);
  
    return filteredOrders.filter((order) => order.status === status).length;
  };

  const operatorsDropdown = (
    <select value={operatorId || ''} onChange={(e) => setOperatorId(e.target.value)}>
      <option value={null}>None</option>
      {operatorsList.map(operator => (
        <option key={operator.id} value={operator.id}>{operator.name}</option>
      ))}
    </select>
  );
 
  const dateRange = generateDateRange();
  
  const stackedData = {
    labels: viewBy === 'month'
      ? Array.from(new Set(orders.map(order => moment(order.created_at).format('YYYY MMM')))).reverse()
      : dateRange,
    datasets: orderStatuses.map((status, index) => {
      const data = viewBy === 'month'
        ? Array.from(new Set(orders.map(order => moment(order.created_at).format('YYYY MMM'))))
            .reverse()
            .map(monthYear => getStatusCount(status, moment(monthYear, 'YYYY MMM')))
        : Array.from({ length: dateRange.length }, (_, i) => getStatusCount(status, dateRange[i]));
      console.log('Data for status', status, data);
      return {
        label: status,
        data: data,
        backgroundColor: `rgba(${index * 30}, ${index * 20}, ${index * 20}, 0.6)`,
        borderWidth: 1,
      };
    }).reverse(),
  };

  const stackedChartOptions = {
    scales: {
      x: {
        stacked: true,
        type: viewBy === 'month' ? 'category' : 'time',
        time: {
          unit: 'day',
          tooltipFormat: 'll',
          displayFormats: {
            day: 'YYYY MMM D',
          },
        },
      },
      y: {
        stacked: true,
        ticks: {
          beginAtZero: true,
          stepSize: 1,
          precision: 0,
        }
      },
    },
  };

  const statusOptions = orderStatuses.map((status) => ({
    label: status,
    value: status,
  }));

 
  const toggleView = () => {
    setViewBy((prevViewBy) => (prevViewBy === 'month' ? 'day' : 'month'));
  };

  return (
    <div className="dashboard-container">
      <div>
        <h3>All Filters</h3>
        <div>
          <label>Start Date: </label>
          <input type='date' value={startDate ? moment(startDate).format('YYYY-MM-DD') : ''} onChange={(e) => setStartDate(e.target.value)} />
          <label>End Date: </label>
          <input type='date' value={endDate ? moment(endDate).format('YYYY-MM-DD') : ''} onChange={(e) => setEndDate(e.target.value)} />
        </div>
        <div>
          <label>Operator: </label>
          {operatorsDropdown}
        </div>
        <div>
          <label>Statuses: </label>
          <MultiSelect
            options={statusOptions}
            value={selectedStatuses}
            onChange={setSelectedStatuses}
            labelledBy="Select"
            // styles={customStyles}
          />
        </div>
        <div>
          <label>View by: </label>
          <button onClick={toggleView}>
            {viewBy === 'month' ? 'View by Day' : 'View by Month'}
          </button>
        </div>
        {orders.length > 0 ? (
          <Bar id="AllFiltersChart" data={stackedData} options={stackedChartOptions}/>
        ) : (
          <p>No orders available for the selected criteria.</p>
        )}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default AllFilters;
```

for this Django 3 endpoints : 1-

```
 class OrderStatus(APIView):
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        order_statuses = [status[0] for status in Order.ORDER_STATUS]
        return Response(order_statuses, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

2-

```
class AllFilters(generics.ListAPIView):
    authentication_classes = [TokenAuthentication]
    permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated]
    serializer_class = GetOrdersSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        start_date_str = self.request.query_params.get('start_date')
        end_date_str = self.request.query_params.get('end_date')
        operator_pk = self.request.query_params.get('pk')
        statuses = self.request.query_params.get('status')

        queryset = Order.objects.all().order_by('-created_at')

        if start_date_str and end_date_str:
            try:
                start_date = datetime.strptime(start_date_str, "%Y-%m-%d").date()
                end_date = datetime.strptime(end_date_str, "%Y-%m-%d").date()
                queryset = queryset.filter(created_at__date__range=[start_date, end_date])
            except ValueError:
                return Order.objects.none()

        if operator_pk and operator_pk.lower() != 'none':
            queryset = queryset.filter(operator=operator_pk)

        if statuses:
            statuses_list = statuses.split(',')
            queryset = queryset.filter(status__in=statuses_list)

        return queryset
```

3-

```
class OperatorsList(generics.ListAPIView):
    authentication_classes = [TokenAuthentication]
    permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated]
    serializer_class = OperationProfileSerializer
    def get_queryset(self):

        return OperationProfile.objects.all()
```

so this is working fine but then I modify this endpoint to add pagination

```
class AllFilters(generics.ListAPIView):
    authentication_classes = [TokenAuthentication]
    permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated]
    serializer_class = GetOrdersSerializer
    pagination_class = PageNumberPagination

    def get_queryset(self):
        start_date_str = self.request.query_params.get('start_date')
        end_date_str = self.request.query_params.get('end_date')
        operator_pk = self.request.query_params.get('pk')
        statuses = self.request.query_params.get('status')

        queryset = Order.objects.all().order_by('-created_at')

        if start_date_str and end_date_str:
            try:
                start_date = datetime.strptime(start_date_str, "%Y-%m-%d").date()
                end_date = datetime.strptime(end_date_str, "%Y-%m-%d").date()
                queryset = queryset.filter(created_at__date__range=[start_date, end_date])
            except ValueError:
                return Order.objects.none()

        if operator_pk and operator_pk.lower() != 'none':
            queryset = queryset.filter(operator=operator_pk)

        if statuses:
            statuses_list = statuses.split(',')
            queryset = queryset.filter(status__in=statuses_list)

        return queryset
```

and then I'm lost I didn't know how to modify my react code to work with pagination and using thunder client to send request the response is correct. Can someone please help me?